# Next JS Route Length

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a url on my Next JS website which shows as `/book/about/dominate_the_practical_formula_to_building_a_profitable_writing_/42325` instead of
`/book/about/dominate_the_practical_formula_to_building_a_profitable_writing_career_on_social_media/42325`

it appears that the slug is shortened instead of showing fully. Please how do i correct this in my Next JS application?

here's what my route code looks like

```js
    routes.add({
       name: 'app.book.index',
       pattern: '/book/about/:slug/:id',
       page: 'book/index'
    })
```

Comment: Which route package you're using?

Comment: @OMiShah "next-routes" package